cross-threading problem with WinForm in C#
I am using C# to display some information in WinForm. I am opening a second WinForm with the information when i received it from a server. I am using the following code to show the second form:
The problem i have is: the second form doesn't refresh anymore. Any control on it (CheckBoxes, drawings e.t.c.) just stop refreshing, and the new status is unknown(like the checkbox is not refreshing the new status). Am i using the Invoke() in a wrong way...
Any help will be appreciated.
private void ShowChartForm(){
   if ((ChartViewForm == null) || (ChartViewForm.IsDisposed)){
      ChartViewForm = new ChartForm();
   }
   try
   {
      if (this.InvokeRequired)
         this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
         {
            ChartViewForm.Show(this);
         }));
      else
        {
           ChartViewForm.Show(this);
        }
    }
   catch
   {
   }
}

I do not have message for cross-threading, but the form is not refreshing.

There's no thread in this code. Unless you call ShowChartForm from a background thread, this runs on the UI thread. You don't need to use InvokeRequired or use Invoke. Beside InvokeRequired and Invoke aren't needed since 2012 when async/await were introduced.

Besides Invoke returns execution to the UI thread so ChartViewForm.Show(this); always runs on the UI thread

You didn't show ChartForm code and I read "doesn't refresh anymore" as certain event handler is not called to fill content of the form. I guess you are not using correct instance when second form is shown, e.g. form itself has static fields, so only one form will work.

What is ChartViewForm?  Is it a property?  If so, is it an auto-property, or does it have code + an explicit backing field?  If it has code, might you please [edit] your question to share the code?

It is not clear in which context ShowChartForm is called. Is it called from another thread, in a loop in an even handler, etc.? If the form already exists, you might try ChartViewForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; ChartViewForm.BringToFront(); instead of Show().

How does ChartViewForm gets data to show? Via this? Or did you just miss giving the data, that you according to you question already have before showing the form, to the form?

There is no problem with the data. i can see the chart diagrams according to the collected data. Something is wrong how i Show/Create the form. I also have a timer on this form , and i noticed that it is not working when i called from the event handler. So, it is not only Refreshing problem, but nothing is working well. Also just for the record: ChartForm is System.Windows.Forms.Form type.

This is the way i made it work:
private void ShowChartForm()
{
   try
   {
      if (this.InvokeRequired)
         this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
         {
            if ((ChartViewForm == null) || (ChartViewForm.IsDisposed))
            {
               ChartViewForm = new ChartForm();
               ChartViewForm.Show(this);
            }
               }));
        else
        {
            if ((ChartViewForm == null) || (ChartViewForm.IsDisposed))
            {
               ChartViewForm = new ChartForm();
               ChartViewForm.Show(this);
            }
         }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}


Do not write code that contains catch{}

You can simplify your code with the InvokeIfRequired(this Control control, MethodInvoker action) extension method from this answer by Olivier Jacot-Descombes.  Or any of the answers from Best Way to Invoke Any Cross-Threaded Code?.

I suspect that calling Show twice on the same form might cause problems. Either reactivate the existing one or create a new one.
private void ShowChartForm()
{
    if (ChartViewForm == null || ChartViewForm.IsDisposed) {
        this.Invoke(() => {
            ChartViewForm = new ChartForm();
            ChartViewForm.Show(this)
        });
    } else {
        ChartViewForm.Invoke(() => {
            ChartViewForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            ChartViewForm.BringToFront();
        });
    }
}

or
private void ShowChartForm()
{
    if (ChartViewForm != null && !ChartViewForm.IsDisposed) {
        ChartViewForm.Invoke(() => {
            ChartViewForm.Close();
        });
    }
    this.Invoke(() => {
       ChartViewForm = new ChartForm();
       ChartViewForm.Show(this);
    });
}

This is the result without Invoke

ShowChartForm() is called from a event handler (MQTT server) so, i need to Invoke, if not - i receive Cross-thread exception. The problem is when i Invoke it nothing is working well (refreshing issue). When i call it through a Button on the main form everything is OK.

Okay, I updated my answer to use Invoke.

You can reduce your code to:
private void ShowChartForm()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
                ShowChartForm();
        }));
    }
    else {
        if ((ChartViewForm == null) || (ChartViewForm.IsDisposed))
        {
           ChartViewForm = new ChartForm();        
           ChartViewForm.Show(this);
        }       
    }
}

